# $\forall n \in \mathbb N \quad F_n \lt 2^{n-1}$ Using Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need some help with proving that $F_n$ (the nth Fibonacci number)  $F_n \lt 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Hope you mind not the edit.

Comment: Are you asking two independent questions, one about $F_n\lt2^{n-1}$, another about the value of $\sum^{\infty}F_n/10^{3n+3}$?

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted that part. 
I think I have managed to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: $2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}<2\cdot2^{n-2}=2^{n-1}$.